# Extracting string after last instance of delimiter in a Batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, split, delimiter

I'm working on writing a Windows batch file that is called by a Java program. A number of different strings denoting file directories are passed into the batch file as parameters. I am trying to figure out how to extract a string after the last instance of the "\". For example, I have three directories:

```
C:\Users\owner\Documents
C:\Users\owner\Videos
C:\Users\owner\Pictures\Trip
```

I would like to split it so that the strings become:

```
Documents
Videos
Trip
```

How would you guys suggest I do this?

EDIT: A follow-up question has been asked here: [For loop in Windows batch file: Error: "The syntax of the command is incorrect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010117/for-loop-in-windows-batch-file-error-the-syntax-of-the-command-is-incorrect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After assigned one parameter to "param" variable, use:

```
for %%a in (%param:\= %) do set lastDir=%%a
```

This method works as long as the last directory does NOT have spaces. This detail may be fixed, if needed. The processing of all parameters would be like this:

```
:nextParam
   set "param=%~1"
   if not defined param goto endParams
   for %%a in (%param:\= %) do set lastDir=%%a
   echo Last dir: %lastDir%
   shift
goto nextParam
:endParams
```

Or, in a simpler way (with no spaces restrictions):

```
:nextParam
   if "%~1" equ "" goto endParams
   echo Last dir: %~N1
   shift
goto nextParam
:endParams
```

Comment: This answer was immensely helpful! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you to all who helped!

Answer (score 4):

If the strings are passed as arguments 1-3. you can use %~n1, %~n2, %~n3 to get the last folder in the path.

Comment: I think this is a good start. I forgot to mention that there is an unknown number of arguments passed in to the batch file, so I would somehow have to have the program determine the number of parameters and do that for each one.

Comment: You could instead create a infinite loop which reads the value at a 'specific (parameter) position and shifts' until the value at that position turns blank.