# Extract last string with delimiter '/' from a file

Tags: regex, string, powershell, split, delimiter

I have a text file which contains a set of strings in the format of a UNIX PATH. I need to extract the last string from each which is delimited by a '/'.

```
/Public/Home/Call/Reports/Weekly Template/C555 Weekly Report - Monday
/Public/Home/Call/Reports/Weekly Template/C567 Weekly Report - Monday
/Public/Home/Call/Reports/Weekly Template/C555 Weekly Report - Tuesday
/Public/Home/Claim Repo/Reports/Weekly Set/@Weekly Report - $100 for Monday
/Public/Home/Claim Report/Reports/Weekly Not Set/ Weekly Report - Monday
```

I need to run these on a Windows box, hence need something on PowerShell or batch.
I need help to work out on the script which can allow spaces and special characters also, and which can read a .TXT file and output the complete string in the format below:

```
/Public/Home/Call/Reports/Weekly Template       C555 Weekly Report - Monday
/Public/Home/Call/Reports/Weekly Template       C567 Weekly Report - Monday
/Public/Home/Call/Reports/Weekly Template       C555 Weekly Report - Tuesday
/Public/Home/Claim Repo/Reports/Weekly Set      @Weekly Report - $100 for Monday
/Public/Home/Claim Report/Reports/Weekly Not Set     Weekly Report - Monday
```

There is a solution which I found in another answer:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004597/extracting-string-after-last-instance-of-delimiter-in-a-batch-file
```

The code for it is given as:

```
for %%a in (%param:\= %) do set lastDir=%%a
:nextParam
   set "param=%~1"
   if not defined param goto endParams
   for %%a in (%param:\= %) do set lastDir=%%a
   echo Last dir: %lastDir%
   shift
goto nextParam
:endParams
```

Or, in a simpler way (with no spaces restrictions):

```
:nextParam
   if "%~1" equ "" goto endParams
   echo Last dir: %~N1
   shift
goto nextParam
:endParams
```

But, I wish to cater for the spaces in the string and the special characters too, which the above does not do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if work

```
(get-content foo.txt) -replace '.*/'
```

Explanation: '.*/' : eat all chars until the last position in string and backtrack until it found the first '/'

```
|a|b|/|c|/|d|
---------|-->
         | <-
         |<--
```

Comment: `-match` returns a boolean True or False - not a string.

Comment: @KeithHill: code is not tested but you can avoid use of match operator here

Comment: @walidtoumi: How do I get the first part of the string also? Can I just extract that into a separate file?

Comment: I wish to have 2 strings - (i) /Public/Home/Call/Reports/Weekly Template and  (ii) C555 Weekly Report - Monday

Comment: @gagneet: you can get first part with this `$data -replace '/(?!.*/).*'`

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you would do this like so:

```
Get-Content foo.txt | Where {$_ -match '/'} | Foreach {$_.Substring($_.LastIndexOf('/')+1)}
```

The `Where` stage of the pipeline is to filter out empty lines and lines that otherwise do not specify a path.

Comment: how do I get the initial string? I want to have it in the format of the initial string <TAB> final string...

Comment: The initial string is in the Foreach scriptblock and is represented by `$_`.