# Extract after delimter in a text file with Batch

Tags: string, batch-file

I have been searching for hours, however most of the results give examples that deal with directories. I need to read a text file to achieve this and extract after the last \ and output into a new file

Below is what my file contains in a text file

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\yahoo.com
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\NYU.edu
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\openssl.org
```

I need to extract all the different strings after the last \ in the string. How do I go about doing this?

I tried this one but it is not working properly [Extracting string after last instance of delimiter in a Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004597/extracting-string-after-last-instance-of-delimiter-in-a-batch-file)

This is on Windows 7 x64 SP1 and I can't install other software to achieve this either.

Comment: Use `for /F "delims=" %K in ("your\string") do echo %~nxK` (double the `%` if used in batch script);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET inFile=C:\SomePath\someFile.txt
SET outFile=C:\SomePath\anotherFile.txt
TYPE NUL>%outFile%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (%inFile%) DO (
    ECHO %%~nxL>>%outFile%
)
```

You'll have to replace inFile and outFile with proper paths. If they contain spaces, surround them with quotation marks.
%outFile% will always be overwritten so make sure you don't loose your data!