# Extracting last folder name from svn repo path in batch after / in a loop

Tags: string, batch-file, slice

I have the following part in a batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (requirements.txt) do (
  set package_path=%%a
  set test_dir_name=!package_path:~4!/tests
  for %%f in ("!package_path:\= !") do set package_name=%%f
  echo !test_dir_name!
  if /i "!test_dir_name:~0,5!"=="https" (
    echo ##### Testing !test_dir_name!\n
    call svn export --force !test_dir_name! tests/!package_name!
  )
)
cp unittest.cfg tests
cp .coveragerc tests
nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml -s tests -c unittest.cfg
python -m coverage xml
@echo J | del /f tests
endlocal
```

In the `requirements.txt` I got svn repositories like this:

```
svn+https:\mysvnserver\svn\tags\1.1.0\Python\my_package
```

I only want to get `my_package` from that string.
That's what I'm trying to do in line 5 above, trying the solution as answered in [Extracting string after last instance of delimiter in a Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004597/extracting-string-after-last-instance-of-delimiter-in-a-batch-file)

But this only splits the path and returns `"svn+https: mysvnserver svn tags 1.1.0 Python my_package"` 
How can I get only `my_package` from the string?

Comment: The accepted answer at your given link does _not_ include any quote: `for %%f in (!package_path:\= !) do set package_name=%%f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=svn+https:\mysvnserver\svn\tags\1.1.0\Python\my_package"
FOR /f "delims=" %%v IN ("%targetdir%") DO (
 ECHO %%v
 ECHO %%~nxv
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should provide you with all the tools to be able to fix your problem.